# I·R drop challenges in advanced node design

Tags: voltage, power-electronics, vlsi

If I·R (current-resistance) drop affects the power grid of a VLSI mixed signal chip on advanced nodes below 7 nm, then why don't we just bump up the voltage to compensate for the loss in I·R drop?

For example: If a 1.5 V supply loses 100 mV due to the resistance in the power network, then just use a 1.6 V supply instead to compensate.

Is it because electromigration (EM) is a positive feedback loop that cannot be stopped?

inc voltage (V) => inc  temp(T) => inc current (I) => inc EM => dec V

Comment: You're attempting an ideal *constant voltage source*. Such a source runs into problems when you short it out - something's going to burn.

Comment: @AlanSaldanha Can you define the acronyms? IR is what?

Comment: They do do that. Why do you think they don't?

Comment: Are you asking about the power grid or about chip design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing voltage leads to a number of tradeoffs, such as (but not limited to) the following:

- Higher power utilization (both static and dynamic) assuming the same parasitic capacitances, operating speed, etc.
- Higher voltage means more hot carrier effects causing damage to FETs
- Thicker oxides required, which makes it harder to drive FETs on and off. I suspect/speculate (but can't confirm 100% with my current knowledge) that thick oxides may also make it harder to manufacture fine-pitch structures.

Generally, for high-speed analog we'd try to use a higher voltage among the ones allowed by the process - assuming we aren't power constrained in some embedded/energy harvesting application.

Comment: I think OP is asking about grid scale power

Comment: @BrendanSimpson The question tags include "VLSI" and title says "advanced node"; to my knowledge while IR drop is a consideration in both VLSI and grid-scale, electromigration (which OP refers to) is not. IIRC "power grid" is also a term that applies to the grid of (usually) topmetal and topmetal-1 to distribute power over a chip

Comment: Yeah I see that, it's a very confusing question. I wasn't trying to criticize just pointing out my interpretation given the reference to the power grid.